# how to get element key in onPress without binding in React Native

Tags: react-native

We already know that the AirBnB style guide discourages using .bind() inside the render function ([source](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react)). As explained [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md):

> A bind call or arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new function on every single render. This is bad for performance, as it will result in the garbage collector being invoked way more than is necessary.

this is what we used to do, passing the param into bind

`renderSingleItem = ({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={func.bind(this, item.id)}>
return <FlatList data={data} renderItem={this.renderSingleItem}/>`

and this seems to be the only way since the param of onPress in React Native doesn't contain target object like ReactJS do.

ReactJS:

`typeof event.taget === 'object'`

React Native:

`typeof event.taget === 'number'`

Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use **memoization** and do

```
<TouchableOpacity key={article.id} onPress={this.goToArticle(article.id)}>
```

and in your `goToArticle` method

```
goToArticle = (articleId) => e => { // ... e are the native events for touch
  console.log(articleId)
}
```

Comment: I considered using [memoize-bind](https://github.com/timkendrick/memoize-bind), but wanted to find a more native way

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
renderSingleItem = ({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
  this.func(item.id)
}>
```